# 'Cannot convert 'double (*)() noexcept' to 'double' in initialization' when defining a max double

Tags: c++

I read that the standard C++ way of using the maximum double value is `std::numeric_limits<double>::max`.

Then in each of my functions where I want to initialize my doubles as the max double I use:

```
#include <limits>
#define MAX_DOUBLE (std::numeric_limits<double>::max)
```

Using gcc -pedantic -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Werror, I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert 'double (*)() noexcept' to 'double' in initialization
```

Can you explain this error?

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<double>::max` is a function. Call it.

Comment: If you want to use a macro, [DBL_MAX](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits) is already available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::numeric_limits<double>::max` is a function in the global namespace rather than a constant. If you are creating the macro, you need to specify the definition as a function identifier

```
#define MAX_DOUBLE std::numeric_limits<double>::max()
```

So passing around MAX_DOUBLE to a double identifier as the error message indicates would mean, initializing a double with a function pointer, the type of which in this case is `double (*)() noexcept` which causes a type mismatch.

Finally for all practical purposes `DBL_MAX` defined in [climits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits) should have served your purpose and thus you would not have been through this torment.

Comment: I disagree with the following comment: "Finally for all practical purposes `DBL_MAX` defined in climits should have served your purpose and thus you would not have been through this torment."

There are benefits to using the generic approach. The mere fact that OP forgot to include the parenthesis doesn't mean that they should have scrapped this approach altogether.

Answer (score 4):

Just as the error message said, you're using a function pointer (`double (*)() noexcept`) as a `double` directly. `std::numeric_limits<double>::max` is declared as a function, you need to call it to get the value.

You can change

```
#define MAX_DOUBLE (std::numeric_limits<double>::max)
```

to

```
#define MAX_DOUBLE (std::numeric_limits<double>::max())
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do define it as:

```
#define MAX_DOUBLE std::numeric_limits<double>::max()
```